# Getting and comparing strings in text file

Tags: objective-c, file

I have text file with the contents of large number of words and now I want to compare with the string with the word in that text file. Is there any way to compare like this.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"dictionary" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *contents = [NSString path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
```

this is the path for my text file and now I have one string

```
NSString *alertstring = [stringadd componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSRange range = [alertstring rangeOfString:@"no"];
if (range.location == NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"word is not there");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"word is there");
}
```

in `alertString` I have word like "no", which is in text file.
When i compare this word with the txt file,
If the word exists in the file,when i am running it is showing as not exist,when i runs second timeit showing as exists.

Comment: From the tag 'iphone' I guess you want to do this in objective-c?

Comment: Could you please attach a sample text file or its contents here.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSRange range = [alertstring rangeOfString:@"aaa"];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    // the string "aaa" wasn't found
}
else {
    // the string WAS found
}
```

Comment: by the way, why did you call your variable "pathfile" when [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:pathforresource encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; returns the file content as string ?

Comment: here the word is exist in the file,but its showing as word not found

Comment: By the way, your content is now in a "contents" variable but we are testing on "alertstrings". Please log the string we are testing on.